# ValueError: One input key expected got ['input', 'agent_scratchpad']

Tags: python, chatbot, streamlit, langchain

I have a chatbot developed using langchain and streamlit. When I run it, it loads perfectly but as soon as I enter the first input it generates an error saying ** "ValueError: One input key expected got ['input', 'agent_scratchpad']"
**
All I want to do is add the response into the memory. Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong in here.

My code looks as below. It's using langchain and steamlit

```
prompt = ZeroShotAgent.create_prompt(
    tools,
    prefix=template,
    suffix=suffix,
    input_variables=["input", "chat_history", "agent_scratchpad"]    
)

memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history")

llm_chain = LLMChain(llm=OpenAI(temperature=0), prompt=prompt,memory=memory)
agent = ZeroShotAgent(llm_chain=llm_chain, tools=tools, verbose=True,return_intermediate_steps=True)

with textcontainer:
    query = st.text_input("Query: ", key="input")
    if query:
        with st.spinner("typing..."):
            conversation_string = get_conversation_string()            

            agent_executor = AgentExecutor.from_agent_and_tools(agent=agent, tools=tools, memory=memory)
            response = agent_executor.run(input=query)
            agent_executor.verbose = True

        st.session_state.requests.append(query)
        st.session_state.responses.append(str(response))
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you need to ensure consistency in the input keys. You can either update the input_variables parameter when creating the prompt to match the keys you are using, or you can adjust the keys you pass when calling agent_executor.run(input=query).

If you want to keep the input_variables parameter as it is, you should pass all the expected keys when calling agent_executor.run() like this:

response = agent_executor.run(input={"input": query, "chat_history": conversation_string, "agent_scratchpad": some_value})

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried your approach with response = agent_executor.run(input={"input": query, "chat_history": conversation_string, "agent_scratchpad": some_value}) but got the same error
ValueError: One input key expected got ['agent_scratchpad', 'input']

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
inputs={"input":query,"chat_history": []}
response = agent_executor.run(inputs)
```